# chaining getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've been looking for an answer to this question but I could find none so I thought I'd try StackOverflow.

In javascript, is this valid:

`x = document.getElementById('myId');
y = x.getElementById('mySecondId');`

I know this can be done with `getElementsByTagName` but I'm not sure if the object returned by `getElementById` is able to use the `getElementById` method.

I know that the ID is supposed to be unique per document, but sometimes this is just not the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) (which extends the `DOMElement` object to support a `getElementById` method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

...But you can, though:

```
Element.prototype.getElementById = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Try it on this page:

```
var x = document.getElementById('footer').getElementById('copyright');
```

Edit: As Pumbaa80 pointed out, you wanted something else. Well, here it is. Use with caution.

```
Element.prototype.getElementById = function(req) {
    var elem = this, children = elem.childNodes, i, len, id;

    for (i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        elem = children[i];

        //we only want real elements
        if (elem.nodeType !== 1 )
            continue;

        id = elem.id || elem.getAttribute('id');

        if (id === req) {
            return elem;
        }
        //recursion ftw
        //find the correct element (or nothing) within the child node
        id = elem.getElementById(req);

        if (id)
            return id;
    }
    //no match found, return null
    return null;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/3xTcX/

Comment: Do not do this, please.  It's unnecessary since you can simply write `document.getElementById()` instead of extending the Element prototype, so it only serves to complicate your code base and confuse the hell out of developers who will inherit the project.  Zero benefit.

Comment: Do not extend Object you do not own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `y = x.querySelector('#'+'mySecondId');` instead of `y = x.getElementById('mySecondId');` in the sample of the question.

`Element.getElementById` doesn't exist but you can add it as mentioned in other answers, even if it is not recommended to add a method to `Element`. In case you want absolutely use this kind of solution, below is a possibility:

```
Element.prototype.getElementById = function(id) {
return this.querySelector("#"+id);
}
```

One advantage to use `element.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementById` inside `Element.prototype.getElementById` is that `element.querySelector` is working even if the element is not already in the DOM, such as after creating it with `document.createElement`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the best way to find out is to try it. In this case, it won't work, since the `getElementById` method is only available on `DOMDocument` objects (e.g. the `document` variable) and not on `DOMElement` objects, which are individual nodes. I think it should have been available on those also, but hey, I disagree with most of the design of the DOM APIs...

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Only the `document` object has the method `getElementById` by default.

Even if `x` was an iframe or something, you'd still have to access some other properties or whatever before you got to another `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using id when there are more than one

Maybe a class or custom attribute is better, you can then use `document.querySelectorAll` to fins them.

```
els = document.querySelectorAll('[custom-attr]')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fast alternative based on [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

```js
var getById = function(id, context) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  return context.contains(el) ? el : null;
}

var container = document.getElementById('container-element');
getById('my-element-id', container);
```

The last line (profiled on latest Chrome and Firefox) performs 4x to 10x faster than jQuery's equivalent

```js
$('#my-element-id', container);
```

The only good alternative is `querySelector` (a bit faster)

```js
container.querySelector('#my-element-id');
```