# document.getElementById for chaining IDs

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a html:

```
<div id="sliderFrame"><div id="slider"></div></div>
```

I want to insert html code into slider div, and I know

```
$('#slider').append('<a class="lazyImage" href="sample.jpg"></a>');
```

will work.

I am wondering if I can achieve this using innerHTML, but I failed to do it because `document.getElementById().getElementById()` can not work.
And I found [chaining getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683087/chaining-getelementbyid) , but I don't quite get it, any one has simpler solution or can explain this?

Comment: Why would you even need to chain multiple `getElementById()` calls instead of just calling it once and going straight to the element you want?

Comment: I don't understand. If you have some working code. Why do you want to change it? Please clarify.

Comment: `getElementById()` is a method of the document object.  It is NOT a method of individual elements which is why you can't chain it.  Also, there should be no reason to chain it because ids are unique in the document and thus you can just do `document.getElementById()` on the end result id and it will be found if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = '<a class="lazyImage" href="sample.jpg">  
                                               </a>'
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got it, I can call it directly on the end result.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one `id` in a page (see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)):

> 7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes
>
> Attribute definitions
>
> id = name [CS]
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. **This
>   name must be unique in a document.**

So assuming your document is well-formed, you only need one `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.innerHTML = '<a class="lazyImage" href="sample.jpg"></a>';
```

but like the comments said, why would you want to do this?  What you have is fine.

Comment: Thanks, because I am using a online slider, and the slider provider said "append" is not supported.