# document.getElementById not working?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why this won't work?

```
var element = document.getElementById('element'); // Works OK
var slide = element.getElementById('slide'); // Throws an error
```

So the idea is to fetch DOM only once, and I have all the tags in that one variable, and then I can manipulate it and get the rest from that variable.

How can I get other elements from `element` variable?
Is it a bad thing to use `document.getElementById('id');` every time I need something from the DOM? Does it slows down webpage?

And how would I solve this problem?

No jQuery please, pure Javascript!

Thanks

Comment: can you show the whole html page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chaining getElementById](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683087/chaining-getelementbyid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) doesn't have `getElementById` method, `document` has,

so use

```
document.getElementById('slide');
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get an element by its id. so it doesn't matter if it's nested inside elements or it's a parent element! because no more than one element in the DOM can have the same ID.

same as getting the first element you have to use:

```
document.getElementById('slide');
```

instead of:

```
element.getElementById('slide');
```

because element variable doesn't have the method getElementById. you get that from document object.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('element');` will get you the control with specific ID from your DOM. So, for getting control with id `slide` as well you will have to use the `document` object

```
document.getElementById('slide');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.prototype.getElementById = function(req) {
    var elem = this, children = elem.childNodes, i, len, id;

    for (i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        elem = children[i];

        //we only want real elements
        if (elem.nodeType !== 1 )
            continue;

        id = elem.id || elem.getAttribute('id');

        if (id === req) {
            return elem;
        }
        //recursion ftw
        //find the correct element (or nothing) within the child node
        id = elem.getElementById(req);

        if (id)
            return id;
    }
    //no match found, return null
    return null;
}
```

So you can use this code

```
var element = document.getElementById('element'); // Works OK
var slide = element.getElementById('slide'); // Will work
```

[From answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683184/1338215)