# JavaScript - add class to child

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
body#page-mod-quiz-attempt
|- div#page-content
  |- div.col.md-3
```

I need to change `div.col.md-3` add `col-sm-12` and `col-xs-12`

I use **js**:

```
var Quiz = document.getElementById('page-mod-quiz-attempt');
var Contenz = Quiz.document.getElementById('page-content');
Contenz.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3").className += ' col-xs-12 col-sm-12';
```

and **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#page-mod-quiz-attempt #page-content div.col-md-3')
    .removeClass()
    .addClass('col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12');
});
```

But failed. Maybe I missed something.
I prefer pure **JavaScript** route if possible.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` will return a list of elements (note that the function states "getElement**s**")

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle I will help you

Answer (score 0):

your html definition uses `div.col.md-3` but your js uses `col-md-3` so first check for typos.

Next, `var Contenz = Quiz.document.getElementById('page-content');` will return an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined`, so if `var Quiz = document.getElementById('page-mod-quiz-attempt')` is not needed. Just use `var Contenz = document.getElementById('page-content');`

Then, `Contenz.getElementsByClassName('col-md-3');` returns an array with the class. so `Contenz.getElementsByClassName('col-md-3').className;` is undefined. Instead `Contenz.getElementsByClassName('col-md-3')[0]` will be the html that is using that class.

Finally you have this: 

`var Contenz = document.getElementById('page-content');
Contenz.getElementsByClassName('col-md-3')[0].className += ' col-xs-12 col-sm-12';`

Which will do what you were asking.
https://jsfiddle.net/onbjhppm/2/

UPDATE: per the comment form OP

If you need to use id="page-mod-quiz-attempt" as the unique identifier, do this instead:

`var Quiz = document.getElementById('page-mod-quiz-attempt');
Quiz.getElementsByClassName('col-md-3')[0].className += ' col-xs-12 col-sm-12';`

https://jsfiddle.net/onbjhppm/3/
Or else add a class identifier to id="page-content" element and chain getElementsByClassName to get to the one you want

Note: `getElementById` is only available on `document`. In order to chain them you will have to create your own function [chaining getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683087/chaining-getelementbyid#5683184)

Comment: i need the "page-mod-quiz-attempt" to identify the page i'm targetting. if i don't use it, all the page on the site will use the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your jQuery as follows will resolve your issue, you also forgot a  period before your class name in the first selector ;) ...

```
$(function() {
  $('#page-mod-quiz-attempt #page-content div.col-md-3').addClass('col-xs-12').addClass('col-sm-12').removeClass('.col-md-3');
});
```